# Sequential search in a binary file

Tags: c, pointers, search, data-structures

I need to find the customer register that is stored in a binary file using his code, as it is defined on the structure above.

```
typedef struct Employee {
    int code;
    char name[30];
    char cpf[11];
    char birthday[11];
    double wage;
} TEmployee;
```

There are 100 registers of the struct above stored in a binary file, and i have to use a sequential search to find a employee by passing his code as a parameter to the search function. Above is the function i´m currently working on. Can you guys give me some help to make this work? The output is always that the employee was not found.

```
TEmployee *sequencial_search(int code, FILE *file) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100) {
        fseek(file, sizeof(struct Employee), SEEK_SET);
        TEmployee *emp = read(file);
        if (code == emp->code) {
            return emp;
        }
        i++;
    }   
    return NULL;
}
```

`read` function:

```
TEmployee *read(FILE *in) {
    TEmployee *emp = (struct Employee *) malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
    if (fread(&emp->code, sizeof(int), 1, in) <= 0) {
            free(emp);
        return NULL;
    }

    fread(emp->name, sizeof(char), sizeof(emp->name), in);
    fread(emp->cpf, sizeof(char), sizeof(emp->cpf), in);
    fread(emp->birthday, sizeof(char), sizeof(emp->birthday), in);
    fread(&emp->wage, sizeof(double), 1, in);

    return emp;
}
```

`main`:

```
FILE *file = fopen("prova1.dat", "wb+");
TEmployee *emp = sequencial_search(8, file);

if (emp != NULL) {
        printf("### EMPLOYEE REGISTER FOUND!!! ### \n\n");
        printf("Code: %d \n", emp->code);
        printf("Name: %s \n", emp->name);
        printf("Cpf: %s \n", emp->cpf);
        printf("Birthday: %s \n", emp->birthday);
        printf("Wage: %.2f \n", emp->wage);
    } else {
        printf("Employee register not found! \n");
        return 1;
    }

free(emp);
fclose(file);
```

Comment: "not working" is never a good problem description. Please give a complete [mre] as well as the exact input, expected result and actual result. Also, what debugging have you dont and where do you find things start going wrong?

Comment: The way the `read` function is used leaks memory for every item that doesn't match. You might consider creating an instance of the struct on the stack in `sequencial_search` and passing that to the `read` function. If you find a match you could use `malloc` to allocate the return value and copy the members into it. You should free that memory once you're done with the return value in `main`.

Comment: As far as the logic in `sequencial_search` goes you return if you don't find the item the first time. You need to continue scanning until you find it or `read` returns an error. You need to remove the seek in the loop too, otherwise you would just read the same item over and over.

Comment: `fseek(file, sizeof(struct Employee), SEEK_SET);` That is seeking to the same spot for every iteration. You don't need to `fseek`. The `fread` calls will naturally advance the file position.

Comment: `printf("Employee register not found!! \n")` You shouldn't be checking/printing that for every loop. You need to search the whole file first before making that decision.

Comment: Using `"wb+"` for the open mode will erase the contents of the file. You probably want just `"rb"`.

Comment: There's a presumption that the 'foreign' binary data file was written conforming to Claudio's hardware and compiler (Big/Little Endian, sizeof int)... You may need to ask for the data as a CSV (a completely different game.)

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

**Size**

Size of `struct` differs from the sum of the size of its members due to padding.

Instead, read a whole `struct`.

```
TEmployee *read(FILE *in) {
  TEmployee *emp = malloc(sizeof *emp);
  if (emp) {
    if (fread(emp, sizeof *emp, 1, in) <= 0) {
      free(emp);
      return NULL;
    }
  }
  return emp;
}
```

**Quitting too early**

If `code == emp->code` is false, function returns.  Better to keep going until `emp == NULL` or `code == emp->code`.

**Memory leak**

Make sure a `free(emp)` occurs for each `malloc()`.

**Why seek?**

`fseek(file, sizeof(struct Employee), SEEK_SET);` not needed. [@kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73430444/sequential-search-in-a-binary-file/73430491#comment129675980_73430444)

**Others?**

Other issues may exist.

---

Tip: size to the object, not the type.

Comment: Reading the whole struct is certainly simpler, but it does depend on the file being written that way. I assumed the individual reads were to match the existing format. Always the trouble with "I'm trying to read a file and it doesn't work but I'm not going to tell you about the file" questions. :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja Agree.  OP did report "here are 100 registers of the struct above stored in a binary file,", so 100 "registers" of size `TEmployee` sounds like the best interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempting to write a line-by-line review of the code, it is less confusing to provide an annotated example of what would achieve your objective. "Don't do this" and "do that this way" can lead to misunderstandings and frustration.

I hope the following is easy to follow, and points you toward your objective.

Before getting into it, though, you need to be aware that "not all `int`s are `int`s" (same, too, for floating point numbers). First off is the difference between 32bit and 64 bit hardware these days. Very old compilers considered `int` to be 16bits. Secondly is the `Big Endian` vs `Small Endian` nature of hardware. It may not be safe to presume that this binary file is what it seems to be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct { // no need for "Employee" token in this source
    int code;
    char name[30];
    char cpf[11];
    char birthday[11];
    double wage;
} TEmployee;

int sequencial_search( char *, int, TEmployee * ); // forward declaration

// main() uses a function to retrieve a single record (or fail to find it)
// prints out info if target record found

int main() {
    char *fname = "prova1.dat";  // filename should be prominent
    int findCode = 8; // target record ID should be prominent

    TEmployee emp; // 'record' buffer to use

    // pass file name, the 'target', and a buffer to be filled in (or not).
    // function returns 0 for failure to open file or find record
    if( !sequencial_search( fname, findCode, &emp ) ) {
        printf( "Employee register not found! \n" );
        return 1;
        // early exit if failed saves one level of indent
    }

    // function succeed, so show what was found
    printf( "### EMPLOYEE REGISTER FOUND!!! ### \n\n" );
    printf( "Code: %d\n", emp.code );
    printf( "Name: %s\n", emp.name );
    printf( "Cpf: %s\n", emp.cpf);
    printf( "Birthday: %s\n", emp.birthday );
    printf(" Wage: %.2f\n", emp.wage );

    return 0;
}

// returns 1 if found and passed buffer valid, or 0 if not found
int sequencial_search( char *fname, int code, TEmployee *emp ) {

    FILE *fp = fopen( fname, "rb" ); // open file here, and ensure it is closed later

    // always test for failure (bad filename, for instance)
    if( fp == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Cannot open %s\n", fname );
        return 0;
        // again, "early return" if cannot proceed
    }

    int found = 0; // an int 'flag' set to 1 if record found

    // read in complete single records
    // let fread() determine how many records it can find
    while( !found && fread( emp, sizeof *emp, 1, fp ) == sizeof *emp )
        found = emp->code == code; // set flag true (1) if this record satisfies

    // found or not, close the file
    fclose( fp );

    return found;
}
```

I don't have your dataset, so cannot fully test that this is correct.